wpebackend-rdk Build Error on YOCTO Kirkstone with i.MX6
I am trying to build WPEBackend-rdk on kirkstone for the i.MX6 but I found this error:
Could NOT find Wayland (missing: WAYLAND_INCLUDE_DIRS)

The content of these variables is empty:

WAYLAND_INCLUDE_DIRS,
WAYLAND_CFLAGS,
WAYLAND_CFLAGS_OTHER,
WAYLAND_LDFLAGS_OTHER

In other hand, the content of these variables is:

WAYLAND_FOUND: 1
WAYLAND_LIBRARIES: wayland-client;wayland-server
WAYLAND_LINK_LIBRARIES: /[build_folders]//work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/wpebackend-rdk/1.20221201-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libwayland-client.so;/[build_folders]//work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/wpebackend-rdk/1.20221201-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libwayland-server.so
WAYLAND_LIBRARY_DIRS: [build_folders]/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/wpebackend-rdk/1.20221201-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib
WAYLAND_LDFLAGS: -L/[build_folders]//work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/wpebackend-rdk/1.20221201-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib;-lwayland-client;-lwayland-server

Knowing that the Wayland dependency is set and the

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/wpebackend = "wpebackend-rdk"
The wpebackend-rdk recipe is: wpebackend-rdk_1.20221201.bb
The wpebackend-rdk sources: master

Can you help me please?

Make sure the recipe has Wayland as backend provider.

Probably the variable DWAYLAND_INCLUDE_DIRS is null or invalid definition, a possible configuration would be: EXTRA_OECMAKE += " -DWAYLAND_INCLUDE_DIRS=${STAGING_INCDIR}/wayland ", you need to check if **DEPENDS** has virtual/egl` specified.
